# Background-size transition on hover makes image shake on safari 11.0.3

Tags: css, safari, css-animations, transition, background-size

I was trying to achieve zoomIn effect of the image with CSS, it works smoothly on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Edge. But on Safari 11.0.3 background-size transition on hover would make image shake unnaturally.

codepen: https://codepen.io/Yumichen/pen/ERyWBV

**CSS:**

```
.img-zoomIn{
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.img-zoomIn:hover{
    background-size: 130% 130%;
}
```

Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this `-webkit-` and see if it works

```
.img-zoomIn{
   -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this property to your class

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
```